# How to build a microservice with scheduler and his be scalable?

Tags: mongodb, web-services, scalability, microservices

I'm building a microservice that integrates data from a SOAP webservice. For this I am using a scheduler that once per day searches for new data and writes to my mongodb database. Since the standard of microservice's is to have one database per service, and my service integrates data and serves that data for another service, how am I going to scale a microservice with these two things together? I will have problem integrating the data, such as duplicated data, so I thought of two solutions:

1 - Divide my microservice in two: one will be responsible for integrating data with webservice SOAP and another will be responsible for serving this data, so I can scale this service. The problem is that it escapes the concept of microservice: a one database for service.

2 - Keep a single microservice and to solve the problem of scalability I could create a parameter to tell the other microservices not to run the scheduler, leaving only a microservice responsible for integrating the data. However, I do not know if this works and it seems to me a bad solution.

What is the best solution? Is there another alternative?

Comment: why do you think is bad to set let the service run the task based on a flag? if you are concerned about overloading your service while the task is running, you could always use a specific instance for running the task, which leads me to ask, why don't just use a cronjob? I mean, this is a very mature scheduler and you should be able to strip a script from your code. Also, on the first point, I think that for most tasks, you don't really need to have separate databases.